# How to specify a specific class in SPARQL?

Tags: class, sparql, rdf, subclass, protege

I am trying to learn ontologies and SPARQL using Protégé.

I'm trying to figure out SPARQL code to show subclasses of a given class:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>               
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX untitled-ontology-10: <http://www.semanticweb.org/chris/ontologies/2022/8/untitled-ontology-10#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?subclass 
WHERE {
  ?subclass rdfs:subClassOf Class.Thing  .
}
```

In the example here I'm trying to find all subclasses of the class Thing (or of any other defined class, e.g. Professions, in my project).

`Class.Thing` doesn't work of course. Neither does `:Thing` nor `ns:Thing` nor `#Thing` nor any of the other variants I've found in examples.

Of course if I use a variable in place of `Class.Thing`, it'll show me *all* classes, but I would really like to narrow it down to subclasses of a specific class.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the URI of the class.

Either as an absolute URI between `<` and `>`:

```
?subclass rdfs:subClassOf <http://www.semanticweb.org/chris/ontologies/2022/8/untitled-ontology-10#YourClass> .
```

Or as a prefixed name (in the same way you already use `rdfs:subClassOf`), using the prefixes you define at the top of your query:

```
?subclass rdfs:subClassOf untitled-ontology-10:YourClass .
```

You could also use the empty prefix, if you define it as such in your SPARQL query:

```
PREFIX : <http://www.semanticweb.org/chris/ontologies/2022/8/untitled-ontology-10#>

# […]

?subclass rdfs:subClassOf :YourClass .
```

---

As default top-class, Protégé uses `owl:Thing` (`http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing`), so that class is not defined under your own ontology’s URI namespace.

(You can change the URI of your ontology in Protégé. If you intend to publish your ontology and/or data, you should use a URI namespace under your control, e.g., under your own domain name.)

Comment: Thanks Stefan, but it doesn't seem to work in my case. I tried both versions; no errors, but no results either.

Comment: Sorry about previous reply, Stefan... it IS in fact working! It doesn't work for top class Thing, but it work sfor my defined subclasses, as in example below:
SELECT  ?subclass
WHERE {
?subclass rdfs:subClassOf untitled-ontology-10:Profession   . 
}
Thank you!

Comment: @ChrisH: Ah yes, that’s probably because the top-class in Protégé is `owl:Thing`, so under the prefix `owl` instead of `untitled-ontology-10`.